# How do batchUpdate calls count towards usage limits?

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

Calls like `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` and `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate` can take multiple update actions in a single call.

I read about google sheets api usage limits at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits, however it is not clear if these calls would count as one or multiple requests. Could you explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` and `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate`, even when multiple requests are included in one batch request of `batchUpdate`, the request uses only one API.

For example, when 10 requests are included in the request body of `batchUpdate` and the request body is run by `batchUpdate`, only one API is used.

About the maximum requests in one batchUpdate, I have never investigated this. But in my experience, when I had used 100,000 requests in one batchUpdate, I could confirm that the script worked fine.

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.