# Google Sheets API limits for Batch Updates

Tags: limit, google-sheets-api

As following the limits described [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/limits)

I'm interested whether [batchUpdat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) including **n** `requests` items would treated as a single query or **n** ones?

And are there any other limits related this call exists? Maybe payload total size or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do batchUpdate calls count towards usage limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537155/how-do-batchupdate-calls-count-towards-usage-limits)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.