# Google forms api - batchUpdate not working in very big form

Tags: google-forms, google-forms-api

I have a very big google form which has more than 200 fields.

While updating the form with batchUpdate, getting below error

```
 "error": {
                "code": 400,
                "message": "Batch update failed: update results in the schema exceeding the entry limit",
                "errors": [
                    {
                        "message": "Batch update failed: update results in the schema exceeding the entry limit",
                        "domain": "global",
                        "reason": "badRequest"
                    }
                ],
                "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
            }
```

Why i am getting above error only for big form? Note: Smaller forms works fine.
Is there any limit for google forms batchUpdate api?

Comment: There are limits on how many reads and writes can be done to a Form. Do you know how many times you make the batch update during the day?

Comment: It's very less. For the smaller it's working fine, at the same it's not working for big form

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the comment.

Depending on how your code works and the size of the Form. You could be looking at the read and writes limits that are applied directly to the Forms as suggested below:

- https://developers.google.com/forms/api/limits

If that is the case you could be looking to the option to apply exponential backoff.

I reviewed any reference about that particular error with Google Drive or Sheets API, where you see a limit on how many updates can be done or limits on cells. Limits for the batch updates might not be available and the best references available are from testing from the community itself, as suggested over this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56537155/how-do-batchupdate-calls-count-towards-usage-limits).

It seems that the limits for those might not be directly disclosed or available for the public as so many other might suggest for similar 400 errors .